# How can I lock the first row and first column of a table when scrolling, possibly using JavaScript and CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, excel, scroll, css-tables

How can I create a table that has its first row and first column both locked, as in Excel, when you activate 'freeze panes'?  I need the table to both scroll horizontally and vertically (a lot of solutions for this exist, but only allow vertical scrolling).

So, when you scroll down in the table, the first row will stay put, since it will have the column headings.  This may end up being in a `thead`, or it may not, whatever makes the solution easier.

When you scroll right, the first column stays put, since it holds the labels for the rows.

I'm pretty certain this is impossible with CSS alone, but can anyone point me toward a JavaScript solution?  It needs to work in all major browsers.

Comment: Hi, I know this is a bit old, but did you get a working solution to this?  The answer marked as correct now has broken links.  I'm trying to find out the same thing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743663/how-do-i-freeze-the-first-and-last-columns-of-an-html-table-in-a-scrollable-div

Comment: I just tried the links in the accepted answer, and they worked for me.  Are you still having trouble?

Answer (score 12):

Oh well, I looked up for scrollable table with fixed column to understand the need of this specific requirement and your question was one of it with no close answers..

I answered this question [Large dynamically sized html table with a fixed scroll row and fixed scroll column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838700/large-dynamically-sized-html-table-with-a-fixed-scroll-row-and-fixed-scroll-colu/10922732#10922732) which inspired to showcase my work as a plugin https://github.com/meetselva/fixed-table-rows-cols

The plugin basically converts a well formatted HTML table to a scrollable table with fixed table header and columns.

The usage is as below,

```
$('#myTable').fxdHdrCol({
    fixedCols    : 3,       /* 3 fixed columns */
    width        : "100%",  /* set the width of the container (fixed or percentage)*/
    height       : 500      /* set the height of the container */
});
```

You can check the [demo and documentation here](http://meetselva.github.io/fixed-table-rows-cols/)

Comment: this is a nice plugin. Any chance for an angular version?

Comment: I followed your good work and I have a question, is all of it prefaced by the fact that you have to provide fixed column widths to the `colModal` array? I have a table with variable column widths and I can't seem to figure out how to get that case operable with your code. I wonder if it's a cascading dependency on colModal's [width property](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options) `width number Set the initial width of the column, in pixels. This value currently can not be set as percentage`

Answer (score 7):

I did this with a combination of:

- Using multiple tables
- Fixed-size cells
- jQuery's scrollTop and scrollLeft functions

Here's a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/software_christian/Fp9a3/8/) to demonstrate.

Haven't tested on all browsers but I imagine it's not great on older IE versions.

```js
$("#clscroll-content").scroll(function() {
    $("#clscroll-row-headers").scrollTop($("#clscroll-content").scrollTop());
    $("#clscroll-column-headers").scrollLeft($("#clscroll-content").scrollLeft());
});

$("#clscroll-column-headers").scroll(function() {
    $("#clscroll-content").scrollLeft($("#clscroll-column-headers").scrollLeft());
});

$("#clscroll-row-headers").scroll(function() {
    $("#clscroll-content").scrollTop($("#clscroll-row-headers").scrollTop());
});
```

```css
.clscroll table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.clscroll td, .clscroll th { 
    overflow: hidden;
}

.corner-header {
    float: left;
}

.column-headers {
    float: left;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.row-headers {
    clear: both;
    float: left;    
    overflow: scroll;
}

.table-content {
    table-layout: fixed;
    float: left;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.clscroll td, .clscroll th { 
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.row-headers, .table-content {
    height: 100px;
}

.column-headers, .table-content, .table-content table, .column-headers table {
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clscroll corner-header">
  <table>
      <tr>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="clscroll column-headers" id="clscroll-column-headers">
  <table>
      <tr>
          <th>Bus</th>
          <th>Plane</th>
          <th>Boat</th>
          <th>Bicycle</th>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="clscroll row-headers" id="clscroll-row-headers">
  <table>
      <tr>
          <th>Red</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th>Green</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th>Blue</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th>Orange</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th>Purple</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th>Yellow</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th>Pink</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th>Brown</th>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="clscroll table-content" id="clscroll-content">
  <table>
      <tr>
          <td>Red Bus</td>
          <td>Red Plane</td>
          <td>Red Boat</td>
          <td>Red Bicycle</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Green Bus</td>
          <td>Green Plane</td>
          <td>Green Boat</td>
          <td>Green Bicycle</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Blue Bus</td>
          <td>Blue Plane</td>
          <td>Blue Boat</td>
          <td>Blue Bicycle</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Orange Bus</td>
          <td>Orange Plane</td>
          <td>Orange Boat</td>
          <td>Orange Bicycle</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Purple Bus</td>
          <td>Purple Plane</td>
          <td>Purple Boat</td>
          <td>Purple Bicycle</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Yellow Bus</td>
          <td>Yellow Plane</td>
          <td>Yellow Boat</td>
          <td>Yellow Bicycle</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Pink Bus</td>
          <td>Pink Plane</td>
          <td>Pink Boat</td>
          <td>Pink Bicycle</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Brown Bus</td>
          <td>Brown Plane</td>
          <td>Brown Boat</td>
          <td>Brown Bicycle</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nicely done, thanks. I forked off that to have only two scrollbars http://jsfiddle.net/2sc64/

Answer (score 4):

You need two tables, where the first one is an exact overlay over the second one. The second one contains all the data, where the first one just contains the first column. You have to synchronize it's width and depending on the content also the height of it's rows.

Additional to this two tables, you need a third one. That's the first row, which lays exactly between the other two and has to be synchronized in the same way.

You will need absolute positioning here. Next, you would synchronize the scrolling of the data table with the scrolling positions of the head row and first column table.

That works very well in all major browsers, except for one issue: The synchronized scrolling will flutter. To fix that, you need two outher div containers that hold a clone of the content of the header row and the first column. When scrolling vertically, you display the header row clone to prevent fluttering, while you reposition the original in the background.
When scrolling horizontally, you would show the first row clone. Same thing here.

Comment: This is way more complex than I originally wanted to go, but ultimately, it was what I ended up doing (more or less).  It seems like this should be a lot easier than it is....

Comment: I agree it seems overly complicated but I can not find any other solution for this.

Answer (score 4):

I've posted my jQuery plugin solution here: [Frozen table header inside scrollable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486576/frozen-table-header-inside-scrollable-div/1533619#1533619)

It does exactly what you want and is really lightweight and easy to use.

Comment: This doesn't seem to support locking the first column. Or am I missing something?  If not, then this solution is no better than the 'common' solution I mentioned in the question.

Comment: I've updated my demo page with locking the first column demo.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few cross browser solutions for this today, among which are [SuperTable](http://www.matts411.com/post/super_tables/) which I like due to its elegance and simplicity (now being continued with MooGrid) and [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki) with its awesome set of features.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to test it but if you embedded an iframe within your page then used CSS to absolutely position the 1st row & column at 0,0 in the iframe page would that solve your problem?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding you, I don't think that would allow the headings to update when the data is scrolled (ie, scroll the row headings down when the data scrolls down so the row headings still correspond to the appropriate rows).

Answer (score 1):

Here a plugin JQuery: https://github.com/nitsugario/jQuery-Freeze-Table-Column-and-Rows

This is a jQuery plugin that can make table rows and columns not scroll.  It can take a given HTML table object and set it so it can freeze a given number of columns or rows or both, so the fixed columns or rows do not scroll.  The rows to be frozen should be placed in the table head section.  It can also freeze rows and columns combined with using colspan or rowspan attributes.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually do-able without JavaScript, but using pure CSS + HTML with sticky position. Just add "position:sticky" to the cells you'd like to freeze.

For building a table, you can either use table tag or CSS grid, and this technique works on both of them.

Here is an example formatting with table tag ( [live demo here](https://codepen.io/tkirby/pen/gOMZJJB?editors=1100) ):

```
<table>
  <tr><th class="head"></th class="head"><th></th> ... </tr>
  <tr><th class="head"></th>             <th></th> ... </tr>
...
</table>
<style type="text/css">
  .head { position: sticky; top: 0; left: 0;}
</style>
```

And here is an example with CSS Grid ( [live demo here](https://codepen.io/tkirby/pen/rNLogXM?editors=1100) ):

```
<div class="grid">
   <!-- cells to freeze -->
   <div class="entry head"></div>
   <div class="entry head"></div>
   ...
   <!-- normal cells -->
   <div class="entry"></div>
   ...
</div>
<style type="text/css">
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(<your-cell-count>, <cell-size>); 
  } 
  .entry.head { position: sticky; top: 0; left: 0 }
</style>
```

You probably will need to take care of the cells frozen both horizontally and vertically ( e.g.,  setting a z-index larger than others ) but it will be still CSS thing.

I think the main drawback of this approach is, probably, the browser compatibility issue. Check [Can I Use CSS-sticky](https://caniuse.com/css-sticky) and [Can I use CSS grid](https://caniuse.com/?search=grid) before using these techniques.

Answer (score 0):

How about a solution where you put the actual "data" of the table inside its own div, with `overflow: scroll;`? Then the browser will automatically create scrollbars for the portion of the "table" you do not want to lock, and you can put the "table header"/first row just above that `<div>`.

Not sure how that would work with scrolling horizontally though.

Comment: Yeah, that works for vertical scrolling, but not for horizontal scrolling.  That is the common solution I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

[Sort and Lock Table](https://jsfiddle.net/58szxy5o/1/) is the only solution I have seen which does work on other browsers than IE. (although this "[locked column css](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=105305)" might do the trick as well).  Required code block below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/dummy.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    /* Scrollable Content Height */
.scrollContent {
 height:100px;
 overflow-x:hidden;
 overflow-y:auto;
}
.scrollContent tr {
 height: auto;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

/* Prevent Mozilla scrollbar from hiding right-most cell content */
.scrollContent tr td:last-child {
 padding-right: 20px;
}

/* Fixed Header Height */
.fixedHeader tr {
 position: relative;
 height: auto;
}

/* Put border around entire table */
div.TableContainer {
 border: 1px solid #7DA87D;
}

/* Table Header formatting */
.headerFormat {
 background-color: white;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 margin: 3px;
 padding: 1px;
 white-space: nowrap;
 font-family: Helvetica;
 font-size: 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.headerFormat tr td {
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 background-color: #7DA87D;
}

/* Table Body (Scrollable Content) formatting */
.bodyFormat tr td {
    color: #000000;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 1px;
    border: 0px none;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 12px;
}

/* Use to set different color for alternating rows */
.alternateRow {
  background-color: #E0F1E0;
}

/* Styles used for SORTING */
.point {
 cursor:pointer;
}
td.sortedColumn {
  background-color: #E0F1E0;
}

tr.alternateRow td.sortedColumn {
  background-color: #c5e5c5;
}
.total {
    background-color: #FED362;
    color: #000000;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
  </style>

  <title></title>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[

/* This script and many more are available free online at
The JavaScript Source :: http://www.javascriptsource.com
Created by: Stan Slaughter :: http://www.stansight.com/ */

/* ======================================================
Generic Table Sort

Basic Concept: A table can be sorted by clicking on the title of any
column in the table, toggling between ascending and descending sorts.


Assumptions:

* The first row of the table contains column titles that are "clicked"
  to sort the table

* The images 'desc.gif','asc.gif','none.gif','sorting.gif' exist

* The img tag is in each column of the the title row to represent the
  sort graphic.

* The CSS classes 'alternateRow' and 'sortedColumn' exist so we can
  have alternating colors for each row and a highlight the sorted
  column.  Something like the <style> definition below, but with the
  background colors set to whatever you want.

   <style>
   tr.alternateRow {
     background-color: #E0F1E0;
   }

   td.sortedColumn {
     background-color: #E0F1E0;
   }

   tr.alternateRow td.sortedColumn {
     background-color: #c5e5c5;
   }
   </style>

====================================================== */

function sortTable(td_element,ignoreLastLines) {

  // If the optional ignoreLastLines parameter (number of lines *not* to sort at end of table)
  // was not passed then make it 0
  ignoreLastLines = (typeof(ignoreLastLines)=='undefined') ? 0 : ignoreLastLines;

  var sortImages =['data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCgAKAMQXAJOkk3mReXume3uTe3mieXGPcXOYc/Hx8Xadds/Wz9vg24ejh3GUcYOgg6a0pnGVcfP18+3w7c3TzdPY06u4q/r8+v///////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAABcALAAAAAAKAAoAAAUz4IVcZDleixQIQjA1pFFZx2FVRklZvOWUl8LsVgBeFLyE8TLgDZYESISwvAAA1QvjAQwBADs=','data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCgAKAMQXAJOkk3mReXume3uTe3mieXGPcXOYc/Hx8Xadds/Wz9vg24ejh3GUcYOgg6a0pnGVcfP18+3w7c3TzdPY06u4q/r8+v///////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAABcALAAAAAAKAAoAAAUw4CVeDzOeFwCgIhFBBDtY1sAmtIIWFV0VJweNRhkZeoeDpWIQNSYBgSAgWYgQLGwIADs=','data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCgAKALMLAHaRdnCTcHegd7C8sNTa1Ku4q9vg24GXgfr8+uDl4P///////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAsALAAAAAAKAAoAAAQfcMlJq12hIHKoSEqIdBIQnslknkoqfedIBQNikFduRQA7','http://web.archive.org/web/20150906203819im_/http://www.javascriptsource.com/miscellaneous/sorting.gif'];

  // Get the image used in the first row of the current column
  var sortColImage = td_element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

  // If current image is 'asc.gif' or 'none.gif' (elements 1 and 2 of sortImages array) then this will
  // be a descending sort else it will be ascending - get new sort image icon and set sort order flag
  var sortAscending = false;
  var newSortColImage = "";
  if (sortColImage.getAttribute('src').indexOf(sortImages[1])>-1 ||
    sortColImage.getAttribute('src').indexOf(sortImages[2])>-1) {
    newSortColImage = sortImages[0];
    sortAscending = false;
  } else {
    newSortColImage = sortImages[1];
    sortAscending = true;
  }

  // Assign "SORTING" image icon (element 3 of sortImages array)) to current column title
  // (will replace with newSortColImage when sort completes)
  sortColImage.setAttribute('src',sortImages[3]);

  // Find which column was clicked by getting it's column position
  var indexCol = td_element.cellIndex;

  // Get the table element from the td element that was passed as a parameter to this function
  var table_element = td_element.parentNode;
  while (table_element.nodeName != "TABLE") {
    table_element = table_element.parentNode;
  }

  // Get all "tr" elements from the table and assign then to the Array "tr_elements"
  var tr_elements = table_element.getElementsByTagName('tr');

  // Get all the images used in the first row then set them to 'none.gif'
  // (element 2 or sortImages array) except for the current column (all ready been changed)
  var allImg = tr_elements[0].getElementsByTagName('img');
    for(var i=0;i<allImg.length;i++){
    if(allImg[i]!=sortColImage){allImg[i].setAttribute('src',sortImages[2])}
  }

  // Some explantion of the basic concept of the following code before we
  // actually start.  Essentially we are going to copy the current columns information
  // into an array to be sorted. We'll sort the column array then go back and use the information
  // we saved about the original row positions to re-order the entire table.
  // We are never really sorting more than a columns worth of data, which should keep the sorting fast.

  // Create a new array for holding row information
  var clonedRows = new Array()

  // Create a new array to store just the selected column values, not the whole row
  var originalCol = new Array();

  // Now loop through all the data row elements
  // NOTE: Starting at row 1 because row 0 contains the column titles
  for (var i=1; i<tr_elements.length - ignoreLastLines; i++) {

   // "Clone" the tr element i.e. save a copy all of its attributes and values
   clonedRows[i]=tr_elements[i].cloneNode(true);

   // Text value of the selected column on this row
   var valueCol = getTextValue(tr_elements[i].cells[indexCol]);

   // Format text value for sorting depending on its type, ie Date, Currency, number, etc..
   valueCol = FormatForType(valueCol);

   // Assign the column value AND the row number it was originally on in the table
   originalCol[i]=[valueCol,tr_elements[i].rowIndex];
  }

  // Get rid of element "0" from this array.  A value was never assigned to it because the first row
  // in the table just contained the column titles, which we did not bother to assign.
  originalCol.shift();

  // Sort the column array returning the value of a sort into a new array
  sortCol = originalCol.sort(sortCompare);

  // If it was supposed to be an Ascending sort then reverse the order
  if (sortAscending) { sortCol.reverse(); }

  // Now take the values from the sorted column array and use that information to re-arrange
  // the order of the tr_elements in the table
  for (var i=1; i < tr_elements.length - ignoreLastLines; i++) {

    var old_row = sortCol[i-1][1];
    var new_row = i;
    tr_elements[i].parentNode.replaceChild(clonedRows[old_row],tr_elements[new_row]);
  }

   // Format the table, making the rows alternating colors and highlight the sorted column
   makePretty(table_element,indexCol,ignoreLastLines);

  // Assign correct sort image icon to current column title
  sortColImage.setAttribute('src',newSortColImage);
}

// Function used by the sort routine to compare the current value in the array with the next one
function sortCompare (currValue, nextValue) {
 // Since the elements of this array are actually arrays themselves, just sort
 // on the first element which contiains the value, not the second which contains
 // the original row position
  if ( currValue[0] == nextValue[0] ) return 0;
  if ( currValue[0] < nextValue[0] ) return -1;
  if ( currValue[0] > nextValue[0] ) return 1;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Functions to get and compare values during a sort.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// This code is necessary for browsers that don't reflect the DOM constants
// (like IE).
if (document.ELEMENT_NODE == null) {
   document.ELEMENT_NODE = 1;
   document.TEXT_NODE = 3;
}

function getTextValue(el) {
  var i;
  var s;
  // Find and concatenate the values of all text nodes contained within the
  // element.
  s = "";
  for (i = 0; i < el.childNodes.length; i++)
    if (el.childNodes[i].nodeType == document.TEXT_NODE)
      s += el.childNodes[i].nodeValue;
    else if (el.childNodes[i].nodeType == document.ELEMENT_NODE &&
             el.childNodes[i].tagName == "BR")
      s += " ";
    else
      // Use recursion to get text within sub-elements.
      s += getTextValue(el.childNodes[i]);

  return normalizeString(s);
}

// Regular expressions for normalizing white space.
var whtSpEnds = new RegExp("^\\s*|\\s*$", "g");
var whtSpMult = new RegExp("\\s\\s+", "g");

function normalizeString(s) {
  s = s.replace(whtSpMult, " ");  // Collapse any multiple whites space.
  s = s.replace(whtSpEnds, "");   // Remove leading or trailing white space.
  return s;
}

// Function used to modify values to make then sortable depending on the type of information
function FormatForType(itm) {
  var sortValue = itm.toLowerCase();

  // If the item matches a date pattern (MM/DD/YYYY or MM/DD/YY or M/DD/YYYY)
  if (itm.match(/^\d\d[\/-]\d\d[\/-]\d\d\d\d$/) ||
      itm.match(/^\d\d[\/-]\d\d[\/-]\d\d$/) ||
      itm.match(/^\d[\/-]\d\d[\/-]\d\d\d\d$/) ) {

    // Convert date to YYYYMMDD format for sort comparison purposes
    // y2k notes: two digit years less than 50 are treated as 20XX, greater than 50 are treated as 19XX
    var yr = -1;

    if (itm.length == 10) {
      sortValue = itm.substr(6,4)+itm.substr(0,2)+itm.substr(3,2);
     } else if (itm.length == 9) {
      sortValue = itm.substr(5,4)+"0" + itm.substr(0,1)+itm.substr(2,2);
    } else {
      yr = itm.substr(6,2);
      if (parseInt(yr) < 50) {
        yr = '20'+yr;
      } else {
        yr = '19'+yr;
      }
        sortValue = yr+itm.substr(3,2)+itm.substr(0,2);
    }

  }



  // If the item matches a Percent patten (contains a percent sign)
  if (itm.match(/%/)) {
   // Replace anything that is not part of a number (decimal pt, neg sign, or 0 through 9) with an empty string.
   sortValue = itm.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g,'');
   sortValue = parseFloat(sortValue);
  }

  // If item starts with a "(" and ends with a ")" then remove them and put a negative sign in front
  if (itm.substr(0,1) == "(" & itm.substr(itm.length - 1,1) == ")") {
   itm = "-" + itm.substr(1,itm.length - 2);
  }

// If the item matches a currency pattern (starts with a dollar or negative dollar sign)
  if (itm.match(/^[£$]|(^-)/)) {
   // Replace anything that is not part of a number (decimal pt, neg sign, or 0 through 9) with an empty string.
   sortValue = itm.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g,'');
   if (isNaN(sortValue)) {
     sortValue = 0;
   } else {
     sortValue = parseFloat(sortValue);
   }
}

  // If the item matches a numeric pattern
  if (itm.match(/(\d*,\d*$)|(^-?\d\d*\.\d*$)|(^-?\d\d*$)|(^-?\.\d\d*$)/)) {
   // Replace anything that is not part of a number (decimal pt, neg sign, or 0 through 9) with an empty string.
   sortValue = itm.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g,'');
 //  sortValue = sortValue.replace(/,/g,'');
   if (isNaN(sortValue)) {
     sortValue = 0;
   } else {
     sortValue = parseFloat(sortValue);
   }
  }

  return sortValue;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Functions to update the table appearance after a sort.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Style class names.
var rowClsNm = "alternateRow";
var colClsNm = "sortedColumn";

// Regular expressions for setting class names.
var rowTest = new RegExp(rowClsNm, "gi");
var colTest = new RegExp(colClsNm, "gi");

function makePretty(tblEl, col, ignoreLastLines) {

  var i, j;
  var rowEl, cellEl;

  // Set style classes on each row to alternate their appearance.
  for (i = 1; i < tblEl.rows.length - ignoreLastLines; i++) {
   rowEl = tblEl.rows[i];
   rowEl.className = rowEl.className.replace(rowTest, "");
    if (i % 2 != 0)
      rowEl.className += " " + rowClsNm;
    rowEl.className = normalizeString(rowEl.className);
    // Set style classes on each column (other than the name column) to
    // highlight the one that was sorted.
    for (j = 0; j < tblEl.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
      cellEl = rowEl.cells[j];
      cellEl.className = cellEl.className.replace(colTest, "");
      if (j == col)
        cellEl.className += " " + colClsNm;
      cellEl.className = normalizeString(cellEl.className);
    }
  }


}

// END Generic Table sort.

// =================================================

// Function to scroll to top before sorting to fix an IE bug
// Which repositions the header off the top of the screen
// if you try to sort while scrolled to bottom.
function GoTop() {
 document.getElementById('TableContainer').scrollTop = 0;
}

//]]> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr><td>
<div id="TableContainer" class="TableContainer" style="height:230px;">
<table class="scrollTable">
 <thead class="fixedHeader headerFormat">
  <tr>
   <td class="point" onclick="GoTop(); sortTable(this,1);" title="Sort"><b>NAME</b> <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCgAKALMLAHaRdnCTcHegd7C8sNTa1Ku4q9vg24GXgfr8+uDl4P///////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAsALAAAAAAKAAoAAAQfcMlJq12hIHKoSEqIdBIQnslknkoqfedIBQNikFduRQA7" border="0"></td>
   <td class="point" onclick="GoTop(); sortTable(this,1);" title="Sort" align="right"><b>Amt</b> <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCgAKALMLAHaRdnCTcHegd7C8sNTa1Ku4q9vg24GXgfr8+uDl4P///////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAsALAAAAAAKAAoAAAQfcMlJq12hIHKoSEqIdBIQnslknkoqfedIBQNikFduRQA7" border="0"></td>
   <td class="point" onclick="GoTop(); sortTable(this,1);" title="Sort" align="right"><b>Lvl</b> <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCgAKALMLAHaRdnCTcHegd7C8sNTa1Ku4q9vg24GXgfr8+uDl4P///////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAsALAAAAAAKAAoAAAQfcMlJq12hIHKoSEqIdBIQnslknkoqfedIBQNikFduRQA7" border="0"></td>
   <td class="point" onclick="GoTop(); sortTable(this,1);" title="Sort" align="right"><b>Rank</b> <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCgAKALMLAHaRdnCTcHegd7C8sNTa1Ku4q9vg24GXgfr8+uDl4P///////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAsALAAAAAAKAAoAAAQfcMlJq12hIHKoSEqIdBIQnslknkoqfedIBQNikFduRQA7" border="0"></td>
   <td class="point" onclick="GoTop(); sortTable(this,1);" title="Sort" align="right"><b>Position</b> <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCgAKALMLAHaRdnCTcHegd7C8sNTa1Ku4q9vg24GXgfr8+uDl4P///////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAsALAAAAAAKAAoAAAQfcMlJq12hIHKoSEqIdBIQnslknkoqfedIBQNikFduRQA7" border="0"></td>
   <td class="point" onclick="GoTop(); sortTable(this,1);" title="Sort" align="right"><b>Date</b> <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCgAKALMLAHaRdnCTcHegd7C8sNTa1Ku4q9vg24GXgfr8+uDl4P///////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAsALAAAAAAKAAoAAAQfcMlJq12hIHKoSEqIdBIQnslknkoqfedIBQNikFduRQA7" border="0"></td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody class="scrollContent bodyFormat" style="height:200px;">
   <tr class="alternateRow">
    <td>Maha</td>
    <td align="right">$19,923.19</td>
    <td align="right">100</td>
    <td align="right">100</td>
    <td>Owner</td>
    <td align="right">01/02/2001</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Thrawl</td>
    <td align="right">$9,550</td>
    <td align="right">159</td>
    <td align="right">100%</td>
    <td>Co-Owner</td>
    <td align="right">11/07/2003</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="alternateRow">
    <td>Marhanen</td>
    <td align="right">$223.04</td>
    <td align="right">83</td>
    <td align="right">99%</td>
    <td>Banker</td>
    <td align="right">06/27/2006</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td align="right">$121</td>
    <td align="right">567</td>
    <td align="right">23423%</td>
    <td>FishHead</td>
    <td align="right">06/06/2006</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="alternateRow">
    <td>Jones</td>
    <td align="right">$15</td>
    <td align="right">11</td>
    <td align="right">15%</td>
    <td>Bubba</td>
    <td align="right">10/27/2005</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Supa-De-Dupa</td>
    <td align="right">$145</td>
    <td align="right">91</td>
    <td align="right">32%</td>
    <td>momma</td>
    <td align="right">12/15/1996</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="alternateRow">
    <td>ClickClock</td>
    <td align="right">$1,213</td>
    <td align="right">23</td>
    <td align="right">1%</td>
    <td>Dada</td>
    <td align="right">1/30/1998</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Mrs. Robinson</td>
    <td align="right">$99</td>
    <td align="right">99</td>
    <td align="right">99%</td>
    <td>Wife</td>
    <td align="right">07/04/1963</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="alternateRow">
    <td>Maha</td>
    <td align="right">$19,923.19</td>
    <td align="right">100</td>
    <td align="right">100%</td>
    <td>Owner</td>
    <td align="right">01/02/2001</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Thrawl</td>
    <td align="right">$9,550</td>
    <td align="right">159</td>
    <td align="right">100%</td>
    <td>Co-Owner</td>
    <td align="right">11/07/2003</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="alternateRow">
    <td>Marhanen</td>
    <td align="right">$223.04</td>
    <td align="right">83</td>
    <td align="right">59%</td>
    <td>Banker</td>
    <td align="right">06/27/2006</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td align="right">$121</td>
    <td align="right">567</td>
    <td align="right">534.23%</td>
    <td>FishHead</td>
    <td align="right">06/06/2006</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="alternateRow">
    <td>Jones</td>
    <td align="right">$15</td>
    <td align="right">11</td>
    <td align="right">15%</td>
    <td>Bubba</td>
    <td align="right">10/27/2005</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Supa-De-Dupa</td>
    <td align="right">$145</td>
    <td align="right">91</td>
    <td align="right">42%</td>
    <td>momma</td>
    <td align="right">12/15/1996</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="alternateRow">
    <td>ClickClock</td>
    <td align="right">$1,213</td>
    <td align="right">23</td>
    <td align="right">2%</td>
    <td>Dada</td>
    <td align="right">1/30/1998</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Mrs. Robinson</td>
    <td align="right">$99</td>
    <td align="right">99</td>
    <td align="right">(-10.42%)</td>
    <td>Wife</td>
    <td align="right">07/04/1963</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="alternateRow">
    <td>Maha</td>
    <td align="right">-$19,923.19</td>
    <td align="right">100</td>
    <td align="right">(-10.01%)</td>
    <td>Owner</td>
    <td align="right">01/02/2001</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Thrawl</td>
    <td align="right">$9,550</td>
    <td align="right">159</td>
    <td align="right">-10.20%</td>
    <td>Co-Owner</td>
    <td align="right">11/07/2003</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="total">
    <td><strong>TOTAL</strong>:</td>
    <td align="right"><strong>999999</strong></td>
    <td align="right"><strong>9999999</strong></td>
    <td align="right"><strong>99</strong></td>
    <td > </td>
    <td align="right"> </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, that works for vertical scrolling, but not for horizontal scrolling. That is the common solution I mentioned in the question.

Comment: This solution has a major advantage over some of the others, which is that the table structure is still intact and makes sense.  For locking only the headers it is possibly the best possible solution.

Comment: Thank you for the comment Mr. Shiny and New. May be this deserves a little bump (+1 in vote) after all ? (Note: this is a community post, no rep gain for me)

Comment: Replaced with JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that I made that is pure javascript/css only.

https://jsfiddle.net/KirbyLWallace/x5sbe0dk/5/

It's meant to be used in full width screen, but I've modified to fit a specific width for the fiddle.

```
<body onResize="scaleElements()">

<div id="table-container-div">

<table id="data-table">
  <thead id="th-header">
    <tr id="th-header-row">
      <td>Column1</td>
      <td>Column2</td>
      <td>Column3</td>
      <td>Column4</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="tbl-body">
    <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>h</td><td>i</td><td>j</td><td>k</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>h</td><td>i</td><td>j</td><td>k</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>h</td><td>i</td><td>j</td><td>k</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>h</td><td>i</td><td>j</td><td>k</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>h</td><td>i</td><td>j</td><td>k</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>h</td><td>i</td><td>j</td><td>k</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>h</td><td>i</td><td>j</td><td>k</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>h</td><td>i</td><td>j</td><td>k</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>h</td><td>i</td><td>j</td><td>k</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>h</td><td>i</td><td>j</td><td>k</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>h</td><td>i</td><td>j</td><td>k</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>h</td><td>i</td><td>j</td><td>k</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>h</td><td>i</td><td>j</td><td>k</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>h</td><td>i</td><td>j</td><td>k</td></tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

javascript:

```
(() => {
        scaleElements();  
    })();


  function scaleElements() {

        // element() is just shorthand for document.getElementById().

        // scaleElements() scales a number of other things, not included here, 
        // that get rescaled any time the browser, or a container is resized.
        // the table header row here is just one of them...
        //
        // this thing includes checks to see if a table with the table & thead 
        // is on the page.  If it is, it checks to see if the span container is
        // here (it's not on the first run, but it is on subsequent calls.  So, 
        // it adds it if it needs it, or reuses it if it's there.

        if (element("data-table")) {

            if (element("th-span-container")) {
                element("th-span-container").parentElement.removeChild(element("th-span-container"));
            }

            var x = document.createElement("div");
                x.id = "th-span-container";
                x.style.cssFloat = "left";
                x.style.position = "fixed";
                x.style.top = "10px";

                // you will want to fiddle with your own particular positioning. 
                // this one is positioned to work on a table that is below a page 
                // logo banner.

            var tds = element("th-header-row").getElementsByTagName("td");

            for (i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {

                let z = tds[i];
                let y = document.createElement("span");

                y.style.padding = "0px";
                y.style.margin = "0px";
                y.style.fontFamily = "'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif";
                y.style.fontSize = "13px";
                y.style.border = "0px";
                y.style.position = "absolute";
                y.style.color = "white";
                y.style.backgroundColor = "#3D6588";
                y.style.left = z.offsetLeft + "px";
                y.style.height = z.offsetHeight + "px";
                y.style.lineHeight = z.offsetHeight + "px";
                y.style.width = z.offsetWidth + "px";
                y.innerHTML = z.innerHTML;
                x.appendChild(y);

            }

            element("table-container-div").appendChild(x);
            element("th-header-row").style.visibility = "hidden";

        }

    }

function element(e) {
    return document.getElementById(e);
}
```

css:

```
body {
  background: black;
}

#table-container-div {
            width: 310px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            bottom: 10px;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: auto;
            min-width: 320px;
        }

        table {
            font-size: 13px;
            height: 120px;
            width: 300px;
            border: 0px solid red;
            background-color: #11171F;
        }

        tr {
            height: 22px;
            color: #cff3ff;
        }

            tr:hover {
                background-color: dimgrey;
            }

        td {
          color:white;
            border-right: 1px dotted #4F4F4F;
        }

        #th-header-row {
            background-color: #3D6588;
            color: white;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran across a site a few weeks back. This is a working example of the first column locked but it is not browser compatible with Firefox. I didn't do a lot of checking around but it seems it only works in IE. There are some notes the author provided along with it that you can read.

Lock the First column:
http://home.tampabay.rr.com/bmerkey/examples/locked-column-csv.html

Let me know if you need the Javascript to lock the Table headers too.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference... currently the link is unreachable, making this a broken answer ;(

Answer (score -1):

You can do it, without javascript

see this link:
http://yonax73.blogspot.com/2014/09/tabla-con-cabecera-estatica-cuerpo-con.html

or live demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/yonatanalexis22/aeeme8mt/7/

```
table{
border-spacing: 0;
display: flex;/*Se ajuste dinamicamente al tamano del dispositivo**/
max-height: 40vh; /*El alto que necesitemos**/
overflow-y: auto; /**El scroll verticalmente cuando sea necesario*/
overflow-x: hidden;/*Sin scroll horizontal*/
table-layout: fixed;/**Forzamos a que las filas tenga el mismo ancho**/
width: 98vw; /*El ancho que necesitemos*/
border:1px solid gray;}
```

Comment: This seems to solve a different problem.  In the jsfiddle you linked, all of the columns fit horizontally, so there is no horizontal scrolling. Part of my question mentioned `When you scroll right, the first column stays put, since it holds the labels for the rows.`  And if they didn't all fit, your CSS will hide the ones the don't fit (`overflow-x: hidden`).  I tried adding more columns, and removing that CSS rule, and the first column scrolled off the screen.  This 'locking the first column' part is what made this a hard problem.