# Emulating Excel's "freeze cells" in an HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, html-table

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I lock the first row and first column of a table when scrolling, possibly using javascript and CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296020/how-can-i-lock-the-first-row-and-first-column-of-a-table-when-scrolling-possibly)

I have an HTML table that contains a large number of rows and columns. The top row contains headers, and the first cell in every row below that contains a header.

I need to allow the user to scroll the table whilst keeping the top row and left column visible at all times (similar to what can be achieved using the "freeze cells" option in Excel.

The solution only needs to work for IE7+ as this is for an internal application.

Ideally the solution should degrade gracefully in other browsers, but that's not essential.

My hunch is that there's a JavaScript solution to this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a duplicate of [How can I lock the first row and first column of a table when scrolling, possibly using javascript and CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296020/how-can-i-lock-the-first-row-and-first-column-of-a-table-when-scrolling-possibly)

Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

As you've said

> The solution only needs to work for IE7+ as this is for an internal application.

There's [this solution](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/scrollingdatagrid/), which is **IE only** and **Css only**.

hope it helps :-)

Comment: ie-only answers are not answers

Comment: @floyd: Except the question says it only has to work in IE7+.