# How do I make a table scrollable

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Does anyone know a vanilla way of making the body of a table scrollable using only html and css?

The obvious solution

```
tbody {
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

does not work.

Wouldnt this be the obvious use of tables?

am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You need to declare a height first, else your table will expand to the according width of its content.

```
table{
   overflow-y:scroll;
   height:100px;
   display:block;
}
```

EDIT: after clarifying your problem I edited the fiddle:
check out [this Example](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/nDmgy/1/) or [that way](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/nDmgy/3/). It's rather hacky and not guaranteed to work crossbrowser but might work for your case.

Comment: what happens to the `thead` part of the table?

Comment: Using `display:block` would work, but generally wouldn't be recommended as the browser would no longer consider it to be a table.

Comment: The examble should solve this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nDmgy/) --and I want the header to stay in place

Comment: @MartinKristiansen you mean, you want to scroll the body while the head stays fixed? You can't achieve with pure css.

Comment: @Christoph: Thats what I wanna do  -- and it would seem like that was exactly what tables were made for -- but from the looks of it, I think your right.

Comment: I like the fix, except from the static td width, is there a way to make that dynamic?

Comment: @MartinKristiansen since the table-properties are destroyed with declaring `display:block` the th and td lose their coupling and thus need fixed widths, unfortunately. Just try to remove them and you will see what I mean.

Comment: You need javascript to achieve the effect you want. I guess there are quite some plugins out there which get you the desired result.

Answer (score 20):

You can't do that with a table. Wrap the table with a div a give it something like:

```
div.wrapper {
    overflow:hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100px; // change this to desired height
}
```

Comment: This should work. Since increasing the height of the table stretches the row alignment.

Answer (score 16):

You can wrap the table with a parent `div` and make him scrollable:

```
.div_before_table {
    overflow:hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 500px;
}
```

And to keep the **table header sticky** you can add a `fixed` class:

```
.th.fixed {
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    position: sticky;
    background-color: white;
 }
```

You can see the example here (click on `Show Code Snippet` and then `Run Code Snippet`) :

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* The scrollable part */

.scrollable {
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not accurate enough. I am using a gradient for the background-color of the table head. Using th makes it to repeat the color from left to right for each column of the table head.

Comment: This code works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Do you want somthing like this ?

Pure CSS Scrollable Table with Fixed Header (1)

http://anaturb.net/csstips/sheader.htm

http://www.scientificpsychic.com/blogentries/html-and-css-scrolling-table-with-fixed-heading.html

Comment: Yep except that I still have to make the width of the cols in the table static. I really really dont wanna have to decide the width before runtime.

Comment: and the second solution is a hack if I ever saw one. without the width tag set, there is absolutely no garantie that the coloms will align with the headers

Comment: A similar question has been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838700/large-dynamically-sized-html-table-with-a-fixed-scroll-row-and-fixed-scroll-colu

Comment: And this code guy suggests to set the width at server side in case you need to set it dynamically.  http://www.cssbakery.com/2010/12/css-scrolling-tables-with-fixed.html?showComment=1337211950779#c1687226751870967064