# HTML table with multiple fixed rows and columns

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, html-table

I have a table like this:

[image: Goal Table]

Now, in reality, there would be in excess of 100 rows and/or columns. Naturally, in such a table, someone might lose track of what they're looking at.
So I'd like a couple (or more) rows and columns to stay fixed in their positions, while only the remaining part of the table scrolls. (So in the picture it'd be only the Cells containing 'Data' should scroll, the rest should stay in place.)

I've tried a couple plugins and they either failed miserably for some reason or were too slow for large tables.

So I'm asking here, is there a way to do this simply through CSS/html/js? Even if it is complicated. The table would be wrapped in a `position: relative` div 
if this matters at all.

Even tho code would be very welcome, I am also open to suggestions. (Kind of new to the whole front end part).

Comment: if i understood your question this is a post talk about fixed table: [fixed table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913118/how-to-make-table-row-fixed-at-the-top)

Answer (score 0):

You could use DataTables.
Here's a link
https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4