# How to create fixed table header rows that include colspans?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have a large dynamic table created from database data. I need the column heading rows to remain fixed and scroll the rows an necessary.

I have tried numerous scripts all over the web trying to get this to work properly.  I'd like to keep this simple and easy on browser, since some target computers are rather lame.

Here is what I'm working with:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sample</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <br><br><br><br>

    <table id="A" border="0" width="95%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="base">
      <tr bgcolor='gray'>
        <td>
          <br><br><br>
          need the blue column heading rows to remain fixed, and scroll the green rows:<br>

    <table id="XYZ" border="1" width="625" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="base">
      <thead>

        <tr>
          <th width="50px" bgcolor="DeepSkyBlue" align="center" valign="middle">Col 1a</th>
          <th width="50px" bgcolor="DeepSkyBlue" align="center" valign="middle">Col 1b</th>
          <th width="75px" bgcolor="DeepSkyBlue" align="center" valign="middle">Col 1c</th>
          <th width="100px" style="border-left:medium solid black;" colspan="3" bgcolor="DeepSkyBlue" align="center" valign="middle"><b>Col 2</th>
          <th width="100px" style="border-left:medium solid black;" colspan="1" bgcolor="DeepSkyBlue" align="center" valign="middle"><b>Col 3</th>
          <th width="150px" style="border-left:medium solid black;" colspan="5" bgcolor="DeepSkyBlue" align="center" valign="middle"><b>Col 4<br>more<br>more</th>
          <th width="100px" style="border-left:medium solid black;" colspan="1" bgcolor="DeepSkyBlue" align="center" valign="middle"><b>Col 5</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th bgcolor="DeepSkyBlue" colspan="3" align="center" valign="middle">Col 1</th>
            <th bgcolor="DeepSkyBlue" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center" valign="middle">A</th>
            <th bgcolor="DeepSkyBlue" align="center" valign="middle">B</th>
            <th bgcolor="DeepSkyBlue" align="center" valign="middle">C</th>
            <th bgcolor="DeepSkyBlue" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center">1</th>
            <th bgcolor="DeepSkyBlue" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center" valign="middle">4-a</th>
            <th bgcolor="DeepSkyBlue" align="center" valign="middle">4-b</th>
            <th bgcolor="DeepSkyBlue" align="center" valign="middle">4-c</th>
            <th bgcolor="DeepSkyBlue" align="center" valign="middle">4-d</th>
            <th bgcolor="DeepSkyBlue" align="center" valign="middle">4-e</th>
            <th bgcolor="DeepSkyBlue" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center">Z</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" colspan="3" align="center" valign="middle">Col 1<br>more</td>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center" valign="middle">A</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">B</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">C</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center">1</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center" valign="middle">4-a</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-b</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-c</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-d</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-e</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center"><input type="text" NAME="b[1]" size="3"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">Col 1a</td>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle">Col 1b+c</td>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center" valign="middle">A</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">B</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">C</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center">1</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center" valign="middle">4-a</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-b</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-c</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-d</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-e</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center"><input type="text" NAME="b[2]" size="3"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle">Col 1a+b</td>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">Col 1c</td>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center" valign="middle">A</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">B</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">C</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center">1</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center" valign="middle">4-a</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-b</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-c</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-d</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-e</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center"><input type="text" NAME="b[3]" size="3"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">Col 1a</td>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle">Col 1b+c<br>more</td>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center" valign="middle">A</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">B</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">C</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center">1</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center" valign="middle">4-a</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-b</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-c</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-d</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-e</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center"><input type="text" NAME="b[4]" size="3"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle">Col 1a+b</td>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">Col 1c</td>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center" valign="middle">A</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">B</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">C</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center">1</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center" valign="middle">4-a</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-b</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-c</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-d</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-e</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center"><input type="text" NAME="b[5]" size="3"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">Col 1a</td>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle">Col 1b+c</td>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center" valign="middle">A</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">B</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">C</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center">1</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center" valign="middle">4-a</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-b</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-c</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-d</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-e</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center"><input type="text" NAME="b[6]" size="3"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle">Col 1a+b</td>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">Col 1c</td>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center" valign="middle">A</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">B</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">C</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center">1</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center" valign="middle">4-a</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-b</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-c</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-d</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-e</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center"><input type="text" NAME="b[7]" size="3"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">Col 1a</td>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle">Col 1b+c<br>more<br>more</td>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center" valign="middle">A</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">B</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">C</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center">1</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center" valign="middle">4-a</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-b</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-c</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-d</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-e</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center"><input type="text" NAME="b[8]" size="3"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle">Col 1a+b</td>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">Col 1c</td>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center" valign="middle">A</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">B</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">C</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center">1</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center" valign="middle">4-a</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-b</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-c</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-d</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-e</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center"><input type="text" NAME="b[9]" size="3"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">Col 1a</td>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle">Col 1b+c<br>more<br>more</td>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center" valign="middle">A</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">B</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">C</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center">1</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center" valign="middle">4-a</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-b</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-c</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-d</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-e</th>
            <td bgcolor="LimeGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center"><input type="text" NAME="b[8]" size="3"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle">Col 1a+b</td>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">Col 1c<br>more<br>more<br>more<br>more<br>more<br>more<br>more<br>more<br>more<br>more</td>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center" valign="middle">A</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">B</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">C</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center">1</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center" valign="middle">4-a</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-b</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-c</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-d</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" align="center" valign="middle">4-e</th>
            <td bgcolor="PaleGreen" style="border-left:medium solid black;" align="center"><input type="text" NAME="b[9]" size="3"></th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

          <br><br><br><br>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <br><br><br><br><br><br>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: could you explain some more, in detail, what you mean by "I need the column heading rows to remain fixed and scroll the rows an necessary" ?

Comment: "I need the column heading rows to remain fixed and scroll the rows an necessary." What do you mean by that exactly? Do you mean that the top row will not scroll, but the rows below it will?

Comment: @Tom,  the actual table I have has over 1000 green rows, I need the two blue header rows to remain visible as you scroll the screen down.

Comment: I know this question has a large promised bounty, but it is simply a more specific duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers

Comment: @Cypress Frankenfeld, I have seen many examples like the one you reference.  My problem is how to make that work for my table, and yes, I'll give away the max bounty points for a working example using my table.

Comment: Could you use ul li structure along with css display styles table(ul), table-row(li) and table-cell(div/span inside li), instead of table, tr and td. Keeping the header fixed for the table and scrolling the tbody may be a difficult task. You can rather have 2 ULs, one for the header and the other one as the body.

Comment: JQuery could be your best friend here, if you do not wish to alter your html.

Comment: @KM. Can you check out my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11887827/297641

Comment: @KM: You found your answer through François Wahl or not? Just mark that as correct or post your own answer...

Comment: Duplicate of your own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838700/large-dynamically-sized-html-table-with-a-fixed-scroll-row-and-fixed-scroll-colu

Comment: @Tiberiu-Ionuț Stan, no, similar, but not a duplicate, read the deails.

Comment: @KM That's what duplicate means around here, similar.

Comment: @Tiberiu-Ionuț Stan, using the "similar" methodology, you could say 90% of the questions on SO are duplicates.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can have the header row(s) in a separate table to the data rows using the same colgroup settings in both.

The below works fine in IE9, FF14.01 and Chrome 20.0.1132.57.

```
<table border="1">
    <colgroup>
        <td width="100px">Column 1</td>
        <td width="100px">Column 2</td>
        <td width="100px">Column 3</td>
        <td width="16px" style="background-color: gray;"><td>
    </colgroup>
</table>
<div style="position: absolute; height:75px; overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:auto">
    <table border="1">
        <colgroup>
            <td width="100px"></td>
            <td width="100px"></td>
            <td width="100px"></td>
        </colgroup>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 1 - Cell 1</td>
                <td>Row 1 - Cell 2</td>
                <td>Row 1 - Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                // rest omitted, see DEMO for full table
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

​See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/KMmpJ/)

**Edit -- August 3rd 2012**

The only way I was able to get it to work was with a bit of trickery alright.
I separated the header as in the first example. But due to the extremly custom multiple different widths in the header, the most reliable way, keeping everything aligned, was to copy the `th` rows **also** into the second table but without text inside. That made them "invisible" but forced the columns in the second table to align as expected.

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pZWkR/)

It feels a bit hackish and I'm sure there is a proper solution but it seems to work well in the meantime.

**Edit -- August 7th 2012**

> Is there any way to "box" this entire table construct up in up 100% of
>   the screen width and change the height for height:150px; to something
>   more dynamic, like $(window).height()-200

There surely is a more elegant way of doing it but I was able to make the table more dynamic.

The width was less of an issue as I capped the toal width at about 95% and hard-capped the table(s) at a `min-width: 600px;` for the header and a `min-width: 584px` for the body, thus ensuring the table stays aligned at all times.

For the dynamic height I used jQuery, binding a resize function to the windows resize event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    resizeTableHeight();

    $(window).on("resize.resizeTableHeight", function() {
        resizeTableHeight();
    });
});

function resizeTableHeight() {
    var headerHeight = $("#tableHeaderContainer").height();
    var documentHeight = $(document).height();
    var spacingHeight = 50;

    $("#tableBodyContainer").height(documentHeight - headerHeight - spacingHeight);
}​
```

When you open the fiddle the original height of the fiddle window will most likely be to high to see the dynamics. Just move the divider and shrink the view to see the re-sizing at work.

Do **not** forget to unbind that event when you are not showing the grid as it still will execute on resize every time.

See dynamic-grid [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/cW5vZ/)

You will notice some styles are in the css (top-right) in the fiddle while others are not. My CSS is not very strong and some styles when I moved them from the elements into the CSS area started to be irgnored. I moved into CSS what I could and left the rest hard-coded not to break it. I'm sure someone working with CSS everyday will be able to sort that out for you.

I also added some ids to some elements for CSS and for the jQuery as required.
I suppose for the CSS it can use classes instead. I leave that to you.

**Summary**
*I'm sure there is a way more elegant way to achieve what you want and probably some script-wiz got a plugin for it. Until then this seems to work. What could also happen is that the columns start miss-aligning close to 600 pixels again if a lot of long data is entered into the columns but as stated, this is a very personalised solution and you may need to add some dynamic calculations for some widths with jQuery over time.*

**Edit -- August 9th 2012**

Regarding setting the width of a td I mentioned in the comments. I fixed the issue with the long text in the first column using the classes I mentioned. Works in IE, FF and Chrome.

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pZWkR/17/)

I used the logic mentioned in the comments. You might find a much better naming convention. I simply used the main-column+ a on/off switch per sub-column. this works out as follows for column 1 styles:

```
.col01-000{
    width: 0px;
}
.col01-001{
    width: 75px;
}
.col01-010, .col01-100{
    width: 50px;
}
.col01-011, .col01-101{
    width: 125px;
}
.col01-110{
    width: 100px;
}
```

I have assigned the first td a class of `col01-100` which means `50px`.
The second td has now a class of `col01-011`, indicating this td still belongs into the first main column but has a width of sub-column 2 (50px) and 3(75px). This adds up to 125px.

I hope this makes sense but if not I gladly continue the discussion in a chat and work the measurements out with you if that is something you want to apply.

So far I can see the measurements to be:

**Col01**

- Col1 = colspan 3 over 175px
- 3 Sub-columns breaking 175px down as follows: 50px-50px-75px

**Col02**

- Col2 = colspan 3 over 100px
- 3 Sub-columns breaking 100px down as follows: 40px-30px-30px

**Col03**

- Col3 = colspan 1 over 100px
- No sub-columns

**Col04**

- Col4 = colspan 5 over 150px
- 5 sub-columns breaking 150px down as follows: 30px-30px-30px-30px-30px

**Col05**

- Col5 = colspan 1 over 100px
- No sub-columns

Comment: I've found many demos like this on the web.  the problem is when I try to make it work on my table, they fail.  My table has two header rows, and use colspans, can you incorporate that into your demo?

Comment: @KM.: I have a look, can't fiddle around with it though until later tonight. I definetly post a response though then.

Comment: looks good.  However, when the table is wider than the screen, the vertical scroll bar is hidden off screen.  Is there any way to "box" this entire table construct up in up 100% of the screen width and change the height for `height:150px;` to something more dynamic, like `$(window).height()-200`

Comment: @KM.: Sorry for the long wait. I wasn't able to sit down and focus on that until tonight. I edited my answer and added a DEMO to a more dynamic grid. I capped the total width of the table at 95% of the screen width with a minimum width of about 600 pixels. Anything below 600 starts causing alignment issues, at least now the table parts will move in sync. I added dynamic height calculations using jQuery as well. Hope this will help point you into the right direction.

Comment: I'm working with the aug 3 version, but having problems where FF wraps the text properly, but IE doesn't, see: jsfiddle.net/pZWkR/11 any ideas?

Comment: @KM: I just checked the issue and yes in IE it seems to only work if a set width per <td> is specified, i.e: 125px for the column with the long test, then it wraps the text as expected. Unless you are able to get one of the plug-ins linked here to work I think you might end up with a custom solution. It might be that you will have to assign an expected px width to each <td>. Using some smart mapper you can automatically assign the correct widths through script.

Comment: @KM: Say for the first column. The maximum length is 175px with a maximum of 3 sub-columns divided into 50px, 50px and 75px. You could use a class on each td to indicate its intended width. i.e: "col01-111". Col01 indicates this td belongs to column 1. As column 1 can have a maximum of 3 sub-columns you have a maximum of 3 numerals (on/off switches) indicating which width to assign. For example `<td class="col01-110">` would indicate you want to use the width of the 1st and 2nd sub-colunmns 50+50 = 100. col01-101 would indicate 1st and 3rd (50+75) = 125px and so on

Comment: I'm generating the html with code, so I can format/calcualte anything.  does every TD need this, just the first row, or just the "problem" ones?

Comment: @KM.: Personally I propably would go through the hassle at the start and apply it to each td. Well, using a mapping mechanism similar to what I mentioned it should be a very automatic process. Using the `colspan` property of the `td` you can easily calculate which `td` belongs to which actual main column and apply the correct class using `$(specificTD).addClass()`. The performance penalty for that should be minimal but you migh find a even better and more efficient way. I just wrote down the first thing that came to mind if I would have had to do it.

Comment: @KM.: If you only address the problem columns now you will most likely have to keep updating it on/off as data changes. I suppose that is a descition that has to be made. As you already need that requirement on some columns it isn't realy a YAGNI (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_Ain%27t_Gonna_Need_It) scenario either. So you might as well automate the process and apply it to each row programatically somehow this time around.

Comment: I have this resolved, without adding a width to every TD.  I put a `width: Xpx` on the `<div>` containing the scrolling table.  I just removed the extra 16px TH spacer in the heading and pushed the DIV's width to the table width + 35, there is a little gap between the scrollbar and the table, but all is fine now.

Comment: @KM.: Sweet. I looked at working on the div as well first but couldn't get it working. Glad you did though. I originally only added the +16px to close that visual "gap" from the scrollbar so it was not realy needed.

Answer (score 11):

**Edit:** Fix for fixed position on window resize:

http://jsfiddle.net/eReBn/13/

**Complete Code:**

```
$(function() {
    (function($) {
        $.fn.fTable = function(o) {

            var tableTmpl = '<table id="XYZ_fixed" border="1" width="625" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="base"></table>';

            this.wrap('<div class="fTable_container" />');
            var fc = this.parent();
            fc.css('width', this.width() + 18);

            this.wrap('<div class="fTable_rContainer" />');
            var rc = this.parent();
            rc.css('height', o.height);

            var fTable = $(tableTmpl);
            fTable
             .addClass('fTable_fixedHead')
             .html(this.find('thead').clone())
             .prependTo(rc);

            $(window).on('scroll resize', function () {
                console.log(isScroll());
                if (isScroll()) {
                    fTable.css('left', $(this).scrollLeft() * -1);
                } else {
                    fTable.css('left', '');
                }
            });
        };

        function isScroll() {
           var root= document.compatMode=='BackCompat'?
               document.body : document.documentElement;
            return root.scrollWidth>root.clientWidth;
        }

    })(jQuery);

    $('#XYZ').fTable({
        height: 300
    });
});
```

---

**Edit:** Try below solution.. since you were ok to manually add styles and adjust table.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/eReBn/12/embedded/result/

**Manual:**

a. Copy below CSS to your style sheet

> ```
> .fTable_rContainer {
>     position: relative;
>     overflow: auto;    
>     height: 300px; /* Height of the table */
> }
>
> .fTable_container {
>     width: 643px;  /* Total width of the table you set + 18px (scroll size) */
> }
>
> .fTable_fixedHead {
>     position: fixed; 
> }
> ```

b. Wrap the Table with div `class="fTable_container"`

c. Copy the `thead` part of the original table and move to a new table as in DEMO.

d. Add class `fTable_fixedHead` to the new table

**Automated with some scripts:**

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/eReBn/11/embedded/result/

---

I tried to solve it using 2 tables,

1. Original table (untouched)
2. Fixed Header table(absolute positioned) over the original table

Check it out and let me know if you like it.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eReBn/7/embedded/result/)

Tested in Firefox & Chrome. [Will test on other browsers later today]

Full code @ http://jsfiddle.net/eReBn/7/

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
   (function($) {
     $.fn.fTable = function(o) {
        /* Preserve the attr list from original table    */
        var el = this[0], arr = [], it;
        for (var i = 0, attrs = el.attributes, l = attrs.length; i < l; i++) {

          it = attrs.item(i);

          if (it.nodeName == 'id') {
           arr.push(it.nodeName + '="' + it.nodeValue + '_fixed"');
          } else {
           arr.push(it.nodeName + '="' + it.nodeValue + '"');
          }
        }

        var tableTmpl = '<table ' + arr.join(' ') + '></table>';

        /* Wrap it inside div's */
        this.wrap('<div class="fTable_container" />');
        this.wrap('<div class="fTable_rContainer" />');

        var rc = this.parent();

        /* Clone the thead and add it to the fixed table head */
        $(tableTmpl)
          .addClass('fTable_fixedHead')
          .html(this.find('thead').clone())
          .prependTo(rc);

        /* Position the fixed head table on scroll */
        rc.scroll(function() {
          rc.find('.fTable_fixedHead').css('top', $(this).scrollTop());
        });

        var _that = this;
        rc.find('.fTable_fixedHead').css('left', _that.aPosition().left);

        /* Position the left on resize*/
        $(window).resize(function() {
          rc.find('.fTable_fixedHead').css('left', _that.aPosition().left);
        });
     };

     /* Position fix for webkit browsers */
     jQuery.fn.aPosition = function() {
        thisLeft = this.offset().left;
        thisTop = this.offset().top;
        thisParent = this.parent();
        parentLeft = thisParent.offset().left;
        parentTop = thisParent.offset().top;
        return {
           left: thisLeft - parentLeft,
           top: thisTop - parentTop
        }
     }
  })(jQuery);
```

});

**Usage:**

```
$('#XYZ').fTable({
    height: 300
});
```

Comment: does this run with little client side processing?  In attempting to use your answer from my previous question, occasionally the table was too large and the browser would crash.  There were several thousand table rows and 50 or so columns, each with a checkbox+onchange script

Comment: @KM. It simply clones the `thead` from the table and use the scroll event. I don't think it would crash.. but let me try to set a fiddle with thousands of rows and see. But is this something close to what you want?

Comment: I seem to have the other solution working without and scroll event or and js so you don't have to.

Comment: @KM. Well it is more of manual vs automated. In other solution, you have to copy paste the `thead` in a separate table and have a div that scrolls. In my solution it is generated by javascript.

Comment: I'm generating the entire page with code, so duplicating the header is trivial.

Comment: @KM. Which other solution are you trying out. You cannot achieve what you want with just 1 table. You either have to cut/copy the `thead` content to a different table for fixed header. It is always better to leave the original table untouched and add necessary unless the copying content is huge. I am working on both manual and automatic solutions for you.. Check out the updated demos and let me know how it looks.

Answer (score 6):

We used [DataTables.net](http://datatables.net/) and solved a very similar problem quite nicely. Here is an [example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html) from their website with an advanced multi-row header. You can also sort within your sub-column categories.

Comment: I use DataTables as well. Works fairly well (only a few oddities that I stumbled upon), and it does a lot of the grunt work for you. Can take some time for larger tables on older browsers though.

Answer (score 6):

I may as well provide an option for you. This assumes the browser window is being scrolled.

The idea here is that a clone of your table is made and everything but the `thead` is stripped out of it. It is fixed to the top of the viewport and hidden.

When the user scrolls past the top of the table, the cloned table is displayed. I have also included a `resize` event to handle changes to the viewport's width. There are some minor hiccups with keeping the fixed header and the table aligned horizontally, but it's not a big issue.

Here is a demo using your table as source (I moved a lot of the inline styles to CSS just to make things easier to read):

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PLjBm/3/)

```
$(function(){
    var $window = $(window),
        stickyTable = $('#XYZ'),
        stickyHeader = stickyTable.clone(true),
        tableTop = stickyTable.offset().top,
        isSticky = false;

    handleScroll();

    $window.on({
        scroll: handleScroll,
        resize: handleResize
    });


    stickyHeader.find('tbody').remove();
    stickyHeader.find('tfoot').remove();

    stickyHeader.addClass('sticky-header').appendTo('body');

    function handleScroll() {
        var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

        if(scrollTop > tableTop && !isSticky) {
            stickyHeader.css('left',stickyTable.offset().left+'px').show();
            isSticky = true;
        } else if(scrollTop <= tableTop && isSticky) {
            stickyHeader.hide();
            isSticky = false;
        }
    }

    function handleResize() {
        if(isSticky) {
            stickyHeader.css('left',stickyTable.offset().left+'px');
        }
    }
});​
```

Comment: Scrolling horizontally should also scroll the header, yet it remains fixed and missaligned.

Comment: @jackwanders Any idea how to also make the header scroll horizontally? This is almost perfect

Answer (score 4):

If you [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the `thead` and put it in the table all of the columns retain their original width.

**Update:** I realized that IE 6 and 7 were having problems and I fixed them. The issue was that those versions of IE don't allow you to position the `thead` directly. As a result, I changed it so that it moves the `thead tr` instead, but only if the browser is IE < 8.

Another bug was that IE < 9 had problems with `.prependTo()`. I'm not sure if it is just IE Tester or not, but I resolved the issue by using `.after()`.

[Updated Demo](http://baylorrae.com/demo-v2.html)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // http://obvcode.blogspot.com/2007/11/easiest-way-to-check-ie-version-with.html
  var Browser = {
    version: function() {
    var version = 999; // we assume a sane browser
      if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) {
        // bah, IE again, lets downgrade version number
        version = parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.split("MSIE")[1]);
      }

      return version;
    }
  }

  var $thead = $('#XYZ thead'),
      $new_thead = $thead.clone().hide(),
      $window = $(window),

      distance_from_top = $thead.offset().top,
      did_scroll = false; // http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

  // for IE <= 7
  var $tr_1, $tr_2;

  // add the cloned thead
  $thead.after($new_thead);

  if( Browser.version() < 8 ) {
    $new_thead.find('tr').css({
      'position': 'absolute',
      'top': 0,
      'margin-left': -1
    });

    $tr_1 = $new_thead.find('tr:first');
    $tr_2 = $new_thead.find('tr:last').css('top', $tr_1.height());
  }else {
    $new_thead.css({
    'position': 'fixed',
    'width': $thead.width(),
    'top': 0
    });
  }

  $window.scroll(function() {
    if( Browser.version() < 8 ) {
      did_scroll = true;
    }

    if( $window.scrollTop() >= distance_from_top ) {
      $new_thead.show();
    }else {
      $new_thead.hide();
    }
  });

  setInterval(function() {
    if( did_scroll ) {
    did_scroll = false;
      $tr_1.css('top', $window.scrollTop());
      $tr_2.css('top', $tr_1.height() + $window.scrollTop());
    }
  }, 250);
</script>
```

---

### Edit

I didn't realize that [K.M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65223/km) wanted a fixed height table. If you look at my example above you'll see that the table header is fixed if the browser scrolls past the top of the table. However, from my understanding this is not what he/she wanted.

I have tested this in the following browsers on my Mac.

1. Safari (5.1.7)
2. Firefox (11.0)
3. Chrome (21.0.1180.75)

And I have tested this in Windows 7 with:

1. IE 8 and 9 using IE Tester
2. Firefox (5.0.1, 6.0.2, 7.0.1, 8.0.1, 10.0.2)
3. Chrome (12.0.742.91)
4. Safari (5.1.5)

It is broken in IE 6 and 7, but I didn't look into seeing if there was a fix.

[Demo](http://baylorrae.com/scrollable-table/)

---

```
var table = $('#XYZ'),
    thead = table.find('thead'),
    fixed_thead = thead.clone(),

    // create a copy of the original table
    fixed_thead_wrapper = $('<table />', {
      'id': 'fixed_thead_wrapper',
      'align': 'center',
      'width': table.outerWidth(),
      'border': '1',
      'cellspacing': 0,
      'cellpadding': 0              
    }).insertBefore(table),

    // this forces the table to be in a scrollable area
    table_wrapper = $('<div />', {
      'id': 'fixed_table_wrapper',
      'height': 300,
      css: {
        'overflow': 'auto'
      }
    });

// add the cloned thead to the new table
fixed_thead_wrapper.append(fixed_thead);

// hide the original thead.
// this is a very hackish way of doing this, but I'm not sure of a better way as of right now
table.css({
  'position': 'relative',
  'top': fixed_thead_wrapper.height() * -1
});

// wrap the original table
table.wrap(table_wrapper);

// line the tables up now that the scrollbar is present
fixed_thead_wrapper.css({
  'position': 'relative',
  'left': table.offset().left - fixed_thead_wrapper.offset().left
});
```

Comment: I've been searching for something that works in IE7, this is it. However in Chrome, IE8, IE9, the table header becomes misaligned by a few pixels horizontally upon scrolling. Any ideas how to sort this?

Answer (score 4):

Some of the previously written answers were brilliant!!

I tested this in Google Chrome most of the time, due to the brilliant Chrome Developer tools for debugging Javascript on the fly, and tweaking css in realtime.

If you added jQuery with a clone function in it, you could achieve a scrollable table without squashing it into a page height, and have a floating Table header wherever you want it

The following code will clone the table header:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("body").append("<table class='tableheader' align='center' border='1' width='625' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'></table>");
    jQuery(".tableheader").append(jQuery(".base2 thead").clone());
```

Then you need to set some static variable, and catch the scrolling event:

```
var headerToMove = jQuery(".tableheader");
var headerOffsetTop = headerToMove.offset().top;
var headerPosition = headerToMove.position();

jQuery(window).scroll(function () { scroll_post_header(); });
```

Then move the header up and down over the current header, but keep it on top of the page, if the current header scrolls out of the way.

```
    function scroll_post_header() {
        var new_position = headerOffsetTop - jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        if (new_position < 0) { new_position = 0;}
        if (headerPosition.top != new_position) {
            headerToMove.css("top",new_position);
            //headerToMove.stop().animate({ 'top': new_position }, 300);
        }
        if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() < 15) { headerToMove.css("top",headerOffsetTop);}
    }
});
```

​
Now ad  some initial CSS to the header that will be cloned. You will need to find that sweet spot where your current header is from the top, but even this can be achieved via jQuery interrogation.

```
.tableheader {
    position: fixed;
    height: 80px;
    top: 160px;
    left: 2.5%;
    z-index: 1000;    
}
```

​
The full working example can be found at: http://jsfiddle.net/webwarrior/YZ8cJ/142/

Hope this helps somewhat without changing any html.

Answer (score 3):

I've always used this super easy to use Plugin that handles it as easily as `$('#tableID').fixedtableheader();`

Works amazingly, very lightweight and flexible.

http://fixedheadertable.com/

Answer (score 3):

Check out [HTML table with fixed headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers). It is the best answer to the general question "how can I freeze a table header?"

Answer (score 3):

**Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vijaysarin/v67uq/1/)**

**Here is the Code. Working fine in all browsers...!**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<title>Scrollable Table with Fixed Header</title>
<meta http-equiv="language" content="en-us">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function removeClassName (elem, className) {
        elem.className = elem.className.replace(className, "").trim();
    }

    function addCSSClass (elem, className) {
        removeClassName (elem, className);
        elem.className = (elem.className + " " + className).trim();
    }

    String.prototype.trim = function() {
        return this.replace( /^\s+|\s+$/, "" );
    }

    function stripedTable() {
        if (document.getElementById && document.getElementsByTagName) {  
            var allTables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
            if (!allTables) { return; }

            for (var i = 0; i < allTables.length; i++) {
                if (allTables[i].className.match(/[\w\s ]*scrollTable[\w\s ]*/)) {
                    var trs = allTables[i].getElementsByTagName("tr");
                    for (var j = 0; j < trs.length; j++) {
                        removeClassName(trs[j], 'alternateRow');
                        addCSSClass(trs[j], 'normalRow');
                    }
                    for (var k = 0; k < trs.length; k += 2) {
                        removeClassName(trs[k], 'normalRow');
                        addCSSClass(trs[k], 'alternateRow');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    window.onload = function() { stripedTable(); }
</script>

<style type="text/css">

body {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #000;
    font: normal normal 12px Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0
}

table, td, a {
    color: #000;
    font: normal normal 12px Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}

h1 {
    font: normal normal 18px Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0
}

h2 {
    font: normal normal 16px Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0
}

h3 {
    font: normal normal 13px Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #008000;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0
}

div.tableContainer {
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid #963;
    height: 285px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 756px
}

html>body div.tableContainer {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 756px
}

div.tableContainer table {
    float: left;
    width: 740px
}

html>body div.tableContainer table {
    width: 756px
}

thead.fixedHeader tr {
    position: relative
}

html>body thead.fixedHeader tr {
    display: block
}

thead.fixedHeader th {
    background: #C96;
    border-left: 1px solid #EB8;
    border-right: 1px solid #B74;
    border-top: 1px solid #EB8;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 4px 3px;
    text-align: left
}

thead.fixedHeader a, thead.fixedHeader a:link, thead.fixedHeader a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%
}

thead.fixedHeader a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: underline;
    width: 100%
}

html>body tbody.scrollContent {
    display: block;
    height: 262px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%
}

tbody.scrollContent td, tbody.scrollContent tr.normalRow td {
    background: #FFF;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
    padding: 2px 3px 3px 4px
}

tbody.scrollContent tr.alternateRow td {
    background: #EEE;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
    padding: 2px 3px 3px 4px
}

html>body thead.fixedHeader th {
    width: 200px
}

html>body thead.fixedHeader th + th {
    width: 240px
}

html>body thead.fixedHeader th + th + th {
    width: 316px
}


html>body tbody.scrollContent td {
    width: 200px
}

html>body tbody.scrollContent td + td {
    width: 240px
}

html>body tbody.scrollContent td + td + td {
    width: 300px
}
</style>
</head><body>
<div id="tableContainer" class="tableContainer">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="scrollTable">
<thead class="fixedHeader">
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <th><a href="">Header 1</a></th>
        <th><a href="">Header 2</a></th>
        <th><a href="">Header 3</a></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="scrollContent">
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>End of Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>End of Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>End of Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: I have found many examples similar to this.  like those, it works great for simple tables, but try using a `colspan` in the header and it fails.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just using JQuery to do `:odd` and `:even` on the row combined with `addClass()` ? Seems overkill for such an easy solution.

Comment: yes http://stackoverflow.com/users/934777/justanotherdeveloper, it's easy with jQuery, but i prefer more JS as i work in GWT.

Answer (score 3):

I have an idea for you. You will split your table into two tables. One of them will acting as the header and the second will acting as the rest of all cells and rows.
The trick in the following:
Placing two fixed width and height divs vertical adjacent to themselves. the upper one will loads the header table and the n the lower will acts for the table body. in the lower div you will set vertical overflow. By this way you will have simple solution's that supports your header move with data scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the best way to go about this is two tables.  Outer table with headers, and one big row with an inner table inside that.  The div should be css'ed overflow: scroll or auto with a set height (via css or javascript).  You will have to set specific widths on all the columns.  I think the best way to go about that is giving a class for each header, and make sure the corresponding columns in the inner table have the same classes.

```
<table>
    <tr><th>...</th></tr>
    <tr><td>
            <div><inner table></div>
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

Check this out for examples: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/tablescroll.html

Answer (score 1):

Very quick and sketchy, but hopefully you get the idea, why not just use `position:fixed` for the thead.
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b3S5F/

Comment: columns way out of alignment on my FF 14