# Fixed tbody line when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to fix the first line (total line) of my table (tbody) so it can be visible when scrolling.

I tried all combination between absolute/fixed/relative position but it didn't work.

Please check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ilyasse/vqTHJ/), I want to fix the "fixedTable" so it can be always visible and to scroll inside the parent div not out of the parent div

```
t
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please include relevant code to your question.

Comment: The simple answer is that it cannot be done.  Search SO - there are loads of questions asking about similar functionality - and there are some workarounds.

Comment: It seems there's a workaround, please check [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10922732/1169519), though there's a lotta of code.

Comment: why 2 tables ? you break the meaning of your table.Use thead and tbody

Comment: Because the code is auto generated by a plugin.

Comment: then you should udate your plugin :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use one single table to keep the sorting and readability of your datas , and fixed thead or tfoot as a trick inside a container.

http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/aJysI This was an answer to a french forum for a table that had row and colspan in header and needed somehow to be scaled without breaking columns.

The trick is to clone thead as a tfoot and set in absolute position tfoot.
Tfoot overlap your table and on topscroll 0, it stands over thead.
Parent container is scrolling table underneath of tfoot.

Comment: no js nor display involved, just a well formed table :)

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't see a table at this codepen fiddle?

Comment: @GCyrillus This is an convincing answer, I guess there's just a typo in the link / wrong link. Can you please fix the link, this looks interesting...

Comment: oups, sorry , here it is : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/aJysI

Comment: I don't know if I was clear, but I need to scroll to right and I want the table to scroll inside the parent div.

Comment: nop, you were not clear, what you want is done with overflow:auto . no magic , just regular CSS to my on opinion ;)