# Fix the first row and the first column in a html table when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xhtml

I have a table in the following form:

```
<table class="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A1</td>
      <td>B1</td>
      <td>C1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A2</td>
      <td>B2</td>
      <td>C2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A3</td>
      <td>B3</td>
      <td>C3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, as the table has lots of rows and columns I would like the first row (Note that the table does NOT have a `<thead>` row) and the first column to be fixed when scrolling.

It is possible to use external JavaScript plugins and change the .css style but I can not modify the structure of the original table. In fact, it can only be accessed via the class selector.

Comment: Check below link that will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838700/large-dynamically-sized-html-table-with-a-fixed-scroll-row-and-fixed-scroll-colu

Comment: You need to use css.
The following link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559197/how-to-make-scrollable-table-with-fixed-headers-using-css