# Frozen Column and Rows for large scrollable table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been painstakingly working on a solution to have a table's column headers scroll with the body when scrolling horizontally and have the first column scroll with the rows when scrolling vertically. I have found solutions that are very close but either use CoffeeScript and Pug or don't work if there is more than one table on the page. This fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/software_christian/Fp9a3/8/ from [How can I lock the first row and first column of a table when scrolling, possibly using JavaScript and CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296020/how-can-i-lock-the-first-row-and-first-column-of-a-table-when-scrolling-possibl) is the intended behavior I am looking for but can't seem to get it working in fiddle, codepen.io or the environment I am developing in. Other solutions I have found that somewhat work seem over-engineered (accepted solution for [Large dynamically sized html table with a fixed scroll row and fixed scroll column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838700/large-dynamically-sized-html-table-with-a-fixed-scroll-row-and-fixed-scroll-colu/10922732#10922732))

Furthermore, the current code I am using works when I put the page/tab on my monitor but not on my actual mac screen. Does anyone know what is going on here and could someone please help me out with a simple dynamic solution using either JQuery, JS, and/or CSS and HTML to solve this problem? I am also trying to maintain the standard HTML structure of a table:

Ideal HTML Format:
(Ideally, I would like a table to remain standard (not scroll) unless I give it a unique class such as "scroll-table")

The below snippets are what I currently have so far.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.scroll-table tbody').scroll(function(e) { //detect a scroll event on the tbody
   
    $(this).siblings('thead').css("left", -$(this).scrollLeft());  scrolling
    $(this).siblings().children().children().css("left", $(this).scrollLeft());
    $(this).children().children().css("left", $(this).scrollLeft());
  });
});
```

```css
.scroll-table {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #aaa;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.scroll-table thead {
  position: relative;
  display: block; 
  width: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}

.scroll-table thead th {
  background-color: #99a;
  min-width: 154px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.scroll-table thead th:nth-child(1) {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell; 
  background-color: #88b;
  min-width: 154px;
  max-width: 154px;
}

.scroll-table tbody {
  position: relative;
  display: block; 
  width: auto;
  height: 239px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.scroll-table tbody td {
  background-color: #bbc;
  min-width: 154px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

.scroll-table tbody tr td:nth-child(1) {  
  position: relative;
  display: block; 
  height: auto;
  background-color: #99a;
  min-width: 154px;
  max-width: 154px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="scroll-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Town</th>
            <th>County</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Profession</th>
            <th>Anual Income</th>
            <th>Matital Status</th>
            <th>Children</th>
            <th>Annual Income</th>
            <th>Marital Status</th>
            <th>Cranes</th>
            <th>Bends</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John Smith</td>
            <td>Macelsfield</td>
            <td>Cheshire</td>
            <td>52</td>
            <td>Brewer</td>
            <td>£47,000</td>
            <td>Married</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>All</td>
            <td>Work</td>
            <td>and</td>
            <td>no</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jenny Jones</td>
            <td>Threlkeld</td>
            <td>Cumbria</td>
            <td>34</td>
            <td>Shepherdess</td>
            <td>£28,000</td>
            <td>Single</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>play</td>
            <td>makes</td>
            <td>Jack</td>
            <td>a</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Peter Frampton</td>
            <td>Avebury</td>
            <td>Wiltshire</td>
            <td>57</td>
            <td>Musician</td>
            <td>£124,000</td>
            <td>Married</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>dull</td>
            <td>boy</td>
            <td>All&nbsp;</td>
            <td>work</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Simon King</td>
            <td>Malvern</td>
            <td>Worchestershire</td>
            <td>48</td>
            <td>Naturalist</td>
            <td>£65,000</td>
            <td>Married</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>and</td>
            <td>no</td>
            <td>play</td>
            <td>makes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lucy Diamond</td>
            <td>St Albans</td>
            <td>Hertfordshire</td>
            <td>67</td>
            <td>Pharmasist</td>
            <td>Retired</td>
            <td>Married</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Jack</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>dull</td>
            <td>boy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Austin Stevenson</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>Lothian</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>Vigilante</td>
            <td>£86,000</td>
            <td>Single</td>
            <td>Unknown</td>
            <td>All&nbsp;</td>
            <td>work</td>
            <td>and</td>
            <td>no</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Wilma Rubble</td>
            <td>Bedford</td>
            <td>Bedfordshire</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>Housewife</td>
            <td>N/A</td>
            <td>Married</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>play</td>
            <td>makes</td>
            <td>Jack</td>
            <td>a</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Kat Dibble</td>
            <td>Manhattan</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>Policewoman</td>
            <td>$36,000</td>
            <td>Single</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>dull</td>
            <td>boy</td>
            <td>All</td>
            <td>work</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Henry Bolingbroke</td>
            <td>Bolingbroke</td>
            <td>Lincolnshire</td>
            <td>45</td>
            <td>Landowner</td>
            <td>Lots</td>
            <td>Married</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>and</td>
            <td>no</td>
            <td>play</td>
            <td>makes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Alan Brisingamen</td>
            <td>Alderley</td>
            <td>Cheshire</td>
            <td>352</td>
            <td>Arcanist</td>
            <td>A pile of gems</td>
            <td>Single</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>Jack</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>dull</td>
            <td>boy</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note: Snippet doesn't seem to be working here. Seems like I can only replicate the behavior I'm seeing on my own machine & monitor :(
Thank you much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided to start from scratch and finally was able to write something that works for multiple tables on a single page and only needs the application of a single class to the main table container to get desired results. Here is the code:

JS -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('scroll-table-1');

        for (var i = 0; i < wrapper.length; i++) {
            wrapper[i].addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {

                var table = this.closest('table');
                var headerRow = table.querySelector('thead');                        
                var firstCol = table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr td:first-child');
                var topLeftCorner = table.querySelector('thead th:first-child');

                headerRow.setAttribute('style','top:' + this.scrollTop + 'px');
                topLeftCorner.setAttribute('style','left:' + this.scrollLeft + 'px');

                firstCol.forEach((n) => {
                    n.setAttribute('style','left:' + this.scrollLeft + 'px');
                });
            });
        };
    });
```

CSS:

```
.scroll-table-1 {
      position: relative;
      display: block; 
      width: auto;
      height: 350px;
      overflow: scroll;
    }

    .scroll-table-1 thead {
      position: relative;
      display: block; 
      width: auto;
      overflow: visible;
    }

    .scroll-table-1 tbody td {
      background-color: #bbc;
      min-width: 154px;
      border: 1px solid #222;
      display: table-cell;
    }

    .scroll-table-1 tbody tr td:nth-child(1) {  
      position: relative;
      display: table-cell; 
      background-color: #99a;
      min-width: 154px;
      max-width: 154px;
      z-index: 10;
    }

    .scroll-table-1 thead th {
      background-color: #99a;
      min-width: 154px;
      border: 1px solid #222;
      word-break: break-word;
      z-index: 15;
    }

    .scroll-table-1 thead th:nth-child(1) {
      position: relative;
      display: table-cell; 
      background-color: #88b;
      min-width: 154px;
      max-width: 154px;
      z-index: 100;
    }
```

The strange thing is that it works perfectly smooth when I scroll on my monitor, but for some reason when I drag the window onto my mac screen the scrolling becomes a bit jittery/jumpy. I have no idea what is causing this nor do I believe it makes any sense but it works so I'll take it for now. If someone has an explanation as to why this bizarre display change behavior happens I would love to hear it.....