# Freeze first two columns and last column of an HTML table that is using both horizontal and vertical scroll without JavaScript

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to freeze the first two columns and last column of an HTML table that is using both horizontal and vertical scroll and haven't been successful. I don't have control of how the table html is output but it matches the way it is structured in the sample below (i.e. thead/tr/th tbody/tr/td. I tried using position absolute on the columns and data but it doesn't look right when scrolling.

I would like to know if it is possible to achieve this without the use of JavaScript.

```css
table {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
      <th>Column 6</th>
      <th>Column 7</th>
      <th>Column 8</th>
      <th>Column 9</th>
      <th>Column 10</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data value 1</td>
      <td>Data value 2</td>
      <td>Data value 3</td>
      <td>Data value 4</td>
      <td>Data value 5</td>
      <td>Data value 6</td>
      <td>Data value 7</td>
      <td>Data value 8</td>
      <td>Data value 9</td>
      <td>Data value 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data value 1</td>
      <td>Data value 2</td>
      <td>Data value 3</td>
      <td>Data value 4</td>
      <td>Data value 5</td>
      <td>Data value 6</td>
      <td>Data value 7</td>
      <td>Data value 8</td>
      <td>Data value 9</td>
      <td>Data value 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data value 1</td>
      <td>Data value 2</td>
      <td>Data value 3</td>
      <td>Data value 4</td>
      <td>Data value 5</td>
      <td>Data value 6</td>
      <td>Data value 7</td>
      <td>Data value 8</td>
      <td>Data value 9</td>
      <td>Data value 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data value 1</td>
      <td>Data value 2</td>
      <td>Data value 3</td>
      <td>Data value 4</td>
      <td>Data value 5</td>
      <td>Data value 6</td>
      <td>Data value 7</td>
      <td>Data value 8</td>
      <td>Data value 9</td>
      <td>Data value 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data value 1</td>
      <td>Data value 2</td>
      <td>Data value 3</td>
      <td>Data value 4</td>
      <td>Data value 5</td>
      <td>Data value 6</td>
      <td>Data value 7</td>
      <td>Data value 8</td>
      <td>Data value 9</td>
      <td>Data value 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data value 1</td>
      <td>Data value 2</td>
      <td>Data value 3</td>
      <td>Data value 4</td>
      <td>Data value 5</td>
      <td>Data value 6</td>
      <td>Data value 7</td>
      <td>Data value 8</td>
      <td>Data value 9</td>
      <td>Data value 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data value 1</td>
      <td>Data value 2</td>
      <td>Data value 3</td>
      <td>Data value 4</td>
      <td>Data value 5</td>
      <td>Data value 6</td>
      <td>Data value 7</td>
      <td>Data value 8</td>
      <td>Data value 9</td>
      <td>Data value 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data value 1</td>
      <td>Data value 2</td>
      <td>Data value 3</td>
      <td>Data value 4</td>
      <td>Data value 5</td>
      <td>Data value 6</td>
      <td>Data value 7</td>
      <td>Data value 8</td>
      <td>Data value 9</td>
      <td>Data value 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data value 1</td>
      <td>Data value 2</td>
      <td>Data value 3</td>
      <td>Data value 4</td>
      <td>Data value 5</td>
      <td>Data value 6</td>
      <td>Data value 7</td>
      <td>Data value 8</td>
      <td>Data value 9</td>
      <td>Data value 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data value 1</td>
      <td>Data value 2</td>
      <td>Data value 3</td>
      <td>Data value 4</td>
      <td>Data value 5</td>
      <td>Data value 6</td>
      <td>Data value 7</td>
      <td>Data value 8</td>
      <td>Data value 9</td>
      <td>Data value 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data value 1</td>
      <td>Data value 2</td>
      <td>Data value 3</td>
      <td>Data value 4</td>
      <td>Data value 5</td>
      <td>Data value 6</td>
      <td>Data value 7</td>
      <td>Data value 8</td>
      <td>Data value 9</td>
      <td>Data value 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data value 1</td>
      <td>Data value 2</td>
      <td>Data value 3</td>
      <td>Data value 4</td>
      <td>Data value 5</td>
      <td>Data value 6</td>
      <td>Data value 7</td>
      <td>Data value 8</td>
      <td>Data value 9</td>
      <td>Data value 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data value 1</td>
      <td>Data value 2</td>
      <td>Data value 3</td>
      <td>Data value 4</td>
      <td>Data value 5</td>
      <td>Data value 6</td>
      <td>Data value 7</td>
      <td>Data value 8</td>
      <td>Data value 9</td>
      <td>Data value 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data value 1</td>
      <td>Data value 2</td>
      <td>Data value 3</td>
      <td>Data value 4</td>
      <td>Data value 5</td>
      <td>Data value 6</td>
      <td>Data value 7</td>
      <td>Data value 8</td>
      <td>Data value 9</td>
      <td>Data value 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data value 1</td>
      <td>Data value 2</td>
      <td>Data value 3</td>
      <td>Data value 4</td>
      <td>Data value 5</td>
      <td>Data value 6</td>
      <td>Data value 7</td>
      <td>Data value 8</td>
      <td>Data value 9</td>
      <td>Data value 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data value 1</td>
      <td>Data value 2</td>
      <td>Data value 3</td>
      <td>Data value 4</td>
      <td>Data value 5</td>
      <td>Data value 6</td>
      <td>Data value 7</td>
      <td>Data value 8</td>
      <td>Data value 9</td>
      <td>Data value 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data value 1</td>
      <td>Data value 2</td>
      <td>Data value 3</td>
      <td>Data value 4</td>
      <td>Data value 5</td>
      <td>Data value 6</td>
      <td>Data value 7</td>
      <td>Data value 8</td>
      <td>Data value 9</td>
      <td>Data value 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data value 1</td>
      <td>Data value 2</td>
      <td>Data value 3</td>
      <td>Data value 4</td>
      <td>Data value 5</td>
      <td>Data value 6</td>
      <td>Data value 7</td>
      <td>Data value 8</td>
      <td>Data value 9</td>
      <td>Data value 10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Large dynamically sized html table with a fixed scroll row and fixed scroll column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838700/large-dynamically-sized-html-table-with-a-fixed-scroll-row-and-fixed-scroll-colu)

Comment: This might be duplicate, pls refer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-a-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-a-scrollable-b

Comment: @Senthil The table is structured differently in the post you are referring to and there is no vertical scroll.

Comment: @HereticMonkeyIt is similar but the table is structured a bit differently without a thead/th and tbody/td and they are using JavaScript. I am wondering if js is required for this.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, using `jQuery` and `css 2 colums are fixed (includes header as well) 
https://jsfiddle.net/spsenthilrm/hadm9Lyw/

Note: The position left is kept on change when the user scrolls, so `jQuery` is required as well for this fixed 2 columns.